# Let's Encrypt check the previous certificat and throw an error

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt

I setup my own landing page on my server with Nginx on top of it. I follow digital ocean 'How to' to get SSL certificat for it.

Now I finish to setup a Wordpress for my wife. Everything working well on plain HTTP but if I try to redo the process with let's encrypt : `sudo certbot --nginx -d pamelajoa.com -d www.pamelajoa.com` cerbot try to challenge the server but find out that there is already a certificat for my own website:

```
IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: pamelajoa.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Incorrect validation certificate for tls-sni-01 challenge.
   Requested
   XXX.YYY.acme.invalid
   from [2001:41d0:8:6d9b::1]:443. Received 2 certificate(s), first
   certificate had names "gfelot.xyz, www.gfelot.xyz"

   Domain: www.pamelajoa.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Incorrect validation certificate for tls-sni-01 challenge.
   Requested
   XXX.YYY.acme.invalid
   from [2001:41d0:8:6d9b::1]:443. Received 2 certificate(s), first
   certificate had names "gfelot.xyz, www.gfelot.xyz"

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

Once again my own web site works on HTTPS and the WP works on HTTP so I don't think it's coming for my Nginx conf.

Any Idea ?

Comment: Is `gfelot.xyz` your website? If so, certbot has trouble injecting its own certificate into nginx, you might have luck using the certbots temporary webserver option instead of nginx.

Comment: Yes exactly it's my own website.
And thank you because it works with the webserver.
The command is `sudo certbot certonly --webroot -w /var/www/pamela -d pamelajoa.com -d www.pamelajoa.com --rsa-key-size 4096` if anyone got the same issue.

Anybody knows why that happen ?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that worked for me by using this option in your command :

`--preferred-challenges http-01`

or you may try to use this one :

`--preferred-challenges http`

Full command here :

`sudo certbot --nginx --preferred-challenges http-01 -d www.kaokeb.com`

*Full post for this solution in this thread :
https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/expired-certification/60185/23*